# How to insert an element when its available?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling on write my code.
What I am trying to do:

- Insert random numbers every few sec next to the "show" elements, when its say its available.

Expected Result

- When its "Not available", no numbers can be inserted in.
- When its "Available", numbers can be inserted in.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(breakdown, 2000);
/*

var myVar1 = setInterval(random, 1000);

function random() {
  var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  let loops = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.show'));
  for (const loop of loops) {
    if () {
      loop.innerHTML = n;

    }
  }
} 

*/

function breakdown() {

  let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.demo'));
  for (const elems1 of elems) {
    let d = Math.random();

    if (d < 0.50) {
      let str = "Available";
      text = str.fontcolor("green");
      x = true;
    } else {
      let str = "Not Available";
      text = str.fontcolor("red");
      y = false;
    }
    elems1.innerHTML = text;
  }

}
```

```html
<p id="demo1" class="demo">
  <p id="show1" class="show"></p>
  <p id="demo2" class="demo">
    <p id="show2" class="show"></p>
    <p id="demo3" class="demo">
      <p id="show3" class="show"></p>
```

Comment: Do you need the random number insertion to be in a separate function?

Comment: Yes, its been sorted, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read other elements' (such as sibling in this case) state ('Available' or 'Not Available') for switching work, you can call the `previousSibling` of the target property then access its innerHTML. Read more about `previousSibling` dom property. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_previoussibling.asp

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vL8gnskp/2/)